# Display another table row (table header/ title) in flutter with Table Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-table

I got a project, where a table widget was used instead of DataTable, So I have been able to pull my JSON data to the table row, but I am having issues showing the header for the table, I can use DataTable to achieve, but I am required to use the table widget.

This is what I have done so far

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: list.isEmpty
              ? Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : Table(
                  columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                    0: FixedColumnWidth(50),
                    1: FixedColumnWidth(300),
                    2: FixedColumnWidth(150),
                    3: FixedColumnWidth(300),
                    4: FixedColumnWidth(150),
                    5: FixedColumnWidth(300),
                    6: FixedColumnWidth(300),
                  },
                  children: list
                      .map((item) => _buildTableRow(
                          item, context))
                      .toList(),
                ),
        )
```

This is my build row function

```
TableRow _buildTableRow(UserModel item, context) {
        return TableRow(key: ValueKey(item.id), children:
  [
    tablecell(item.name),
    tablecell(item.email),
    tablecell(item.phone),
   
  ]
}
```

The challenge is to add titles to the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```dart
children:[ 
    /// your Header 
    ...list.map((item) => _buildTableRow(item, context)).toList(),
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use decoration property of 'TableRow' like following, to make it look like header :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: list.isEmpty
              ? Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : _tableWidget(list),
        )
```

// Table widget method :

```
      Widget _tableWidget(list) {
        if (list == null) {
          return Container();
        }
        int rowLength = list.length + 1; //+1 for titles
        List<TableRow> rows = [];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
          List<Widget> columns = [];
          bool isHeader = i == 0;
    
          columns.add(tablecell(isHeader ? "Name" : list[i - 1].name));
          columns.add(tablecell(isHeader ? "Email" : list[i - 1].email));
          columns.add(tablecell(isHeader ? "Phone" : list[i - 1].phone));
    
          rows.add(TableRow(
            decoration: isHeader ? _selectedDecoration() : _deselectedDecoration(),
            children: columns,
          ));
        }
        try {
          return Table(
            defaultColumnWidth: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
            border: null,
            children: rows,
          );
        } catch (e) {
          return Text(e.toString());
        }
      }
```

// Modify these according to your requirement

```
      _selectedDecoration() {
        return BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
        );
      }
    

      _deselectedDecoration() {
        return BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
          color: Colors.white,
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried and it work but @yeasin-sheikh method is shorter